# Stop window from maximizing after event if window is minimized

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have this code which alerts after 3 sec of inactivity. The problem is when i have this window minimized after 3 sec it shows back. How can i stop this maximizing back on alert?
My second question: is my script ok or has any problems?

```
var reloadtimer;    
$(document).on('keyup keypress change mousemove click scroll',function(){ 
   resetTimer();
});    
function resetTimer() {
  clearTimeout(reloadtimer);
  reloadtimer = setTimeout(function(){ alert("inactive"); }, 3000);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/OreGomaS/1/)

Comment: simple solution will be to not use modal alert() but instead a customized alerting method

Comment: It works minimized as expected (without restoring window) on Firefox 26 and Linux OS. Try writing things via console.log. Alert is there for debugging only, right?

Comment: @akhikhl actually i'm reloading the page after alert

Comment: @A.Wolff i'll try bootstrap modal. Are these events enough or should i add some more event to check inactivity?